# Asp.net MVC 3 - controller action doesn't see the JSON object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I implemented a small test that is based on Scott Guthrie article
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx

But my controller action thinks that object passed to it is null, even though I used JSON.stringify on it and packed data to it - I followed the article exactly.

In my html

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FormID" })) {  


    <div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)</div>   
    <div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)</div>    
    <div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)</div>


    <input type="button" value="save" onclick="Save();" />
}
```

In my model file

```
namespace MyNamespace.Models
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string DateReceived { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my js

```
function Save() {   

     var myModelObj = { Id: $("#Id").val(),
               DateReceived: $("#DateReceived").val(),
               Name: $("#Name").val()
    };


$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "/ControllerName/SomeAction",
    data: JSON.stringify(myModelObj),
    cache: false,
   //  dataType: "json",

    success: function (data) {

        alert('success!');
    },

    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        alert('error');
        alert(XMLHttpRequest + "<br />" + textStatus + "<br />" + errorThrown);

    }

});
```

In my controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeAction(MyModel modelObj )
    {
       using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("/test.txt") )
        {

            sw.Write(modelObj.Id);
        } 
        return null;
    }
```

When I put a break point on sw.Write...statement, modelObj.Id is null.

Am I missing something or is there anything else that needs to be wired up? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add the contentType and dataType options to your ajax call.

```
contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
dataType: 'json',
```

Comment: nope still null. I guess the promised functionality never happened? can anyone elaborate please?

Comment: No. The functionality is definitely there. I use it quite a bit. Let me look more closely at your code.

Comment: I also noticed that sw.Write("some test text"); doesn't work either...not sure if that is somehow related. It looks like this Controller/Action just does nothing, but the execution definitely goes there as I put breakpoints

Comment: I got it! In my model I had other fields that I was not populating in js. I erroneously assumed that you can populate part of the fields. I will mark yours as an answer.

Comment: Great. Glad you got it figured out. This is a great feature of MVC 3, you'll like it!